# How to string interpolate in bash functions

Tags: bash, zshrc

I'm trying to create a function with two parameters, but the second parameter is supposed to go within a string and hence I'm having issues passing that as a parameter

My function (Notice the second instance of $1 -> '["src/**/$1.ts"]')

```
cov() {
  yarn jest $1 --collectCoverageFrom='["src/**/$1.ts"]' --selectProjects '@bdc/neo' --coverage --verbose
}
```

Example command

```
yarn jest auto-fill-vendor.component --collectCoverageFrom='["src/**/auto-fill-vendor.component.ts"]' --selectProjects '@bdc/neo' --coverage --verbose
```

Comment: That's not an alias, it's a function. And parameters don't expand inside single quotes.

Comment: please review/update your question ... I don't see any reference to a 2nd parameter (eg, `$2`), and you haven't provided any examples of calling the function; also, you've mentioned `alias` a coiuple times (title, description) but the code you've provided (`cov()`) is a function ... aliases and functions are not the same thing so it would help clear up some confusion if you also update the title/question with the correct terminology

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes to allow parameter expansion.

```
cov() {
    yarn jest "$1" \
           --collectCoverageFrom="[\"src/**/$1.ts\"]" \
           --selectProjects '@bdc/neo' \
           --coverage \
           --verbose
}

cov auto-fill-vendor.component
```

Inside the double quotes, you'll have to escape the literal double quotes.